# how to match string in perl with a variable rather than regex

Tags: arrays, regex, string, perl, string-matching

I have an array of file names that I want to detect using perl.

I have a lot more than these, but this example is just to illustrate:

```
@toremove = (100, 102, 104, 131, 156);
```

Now I want to open the directory and go through the files and if they happen to have any of the filenames as in the array above, I want to take some action.

```
opendir (DIR, "D:/MYPATH/");
while (my $file = readdir(DIR)) {
    if($file =~ <how do i reference an array item here?>.txt)
    { // do something }
```

Is there any way to say if the file happens to match any of the items in the array? So this is more like a "variable string match"...

Answer (score 2):

I'd transform the array to hash first and then simply test if the key exists in the hash.

```
my @toremove = (100, 102, 104, 131, 156);
my %lookup_hash;
$lookup_hash{"$_.txt"} = 1 for @toremove;

opendir (my $DIR, "D:/MYPATH/");
while (my $file = readdir($DIR)) {
    if( $lookup_hash{$file} )
    { // do something }
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you say to yourself *How can I quickly find something in a list*, you should say to yourself *Hash!*.

Let's take that `@toremove` list, and turn it into a hash. We can do this with the [*map*](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) command. The [*map*](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) command is a bit scary at first, and I don't believe the manpage for it does it justice. It isn't really that complex:

```
 @some_hash_or_array = map { .... } @original_array;
```

[*map*](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) takes `@original_array` and loops through each entry of that array. The `{...}` is a small program you want to run on each entry.

You can think of [*map*](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) as *something* like this:

```
my @original_array = qw( ... );
my @some_hash_or_array;
for my $entry ( @original_array ) {
    push @some_hash_or_array, { ... };
}
```

What makes [*map*](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) useful is that each entry of the array is set to `$_`, so manipulating `$_` allows you to transform your array.

What I am doing is:

```
my %files = map { $_.".txt" => 1 } @to_remove;
```

When this [*map*](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) command processes `@to_remove`, it creates another array that looks like this:

```
("100.txt" => 1, "102.txt" => 1, "104.txt" => 1, "131.txt" => 1, "156.txt" => 1)
```

I initialize my `%files` hash with this array. Odd entries are the *keys* to the hash and the even entries following the keys are the data.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#
use strict;             # Lets you know when you misspell variable names
use warnings;           # Warns of issues (using undefined variables)
use feature qw(say);

my @to_remove = qw(100 102 104 131 156);

my %files = map { $_.".txt" => 1 } @to_remove;
while ( my $file = <DATA> ) {
    chomp $file;
    if ( exists $files{$file} ) {
        say qq(File "$file" is in the list);
    }
    else {
        say qq(File "$file" isn't in the list);
    }
}

__DATA__
100.txt
203.txt
130.txt
104.txt
150.txt
156.txt
160.txt
```

This produces:

```
File "100.txt" is in the list
File "203.txt" isn't in the list
File "130.txt" isn't in the list
File "104.txt" is in the list
File "150.txt" isn't in the list
File "156.txt" is in the list
File "160.txt" isn't in the list
```

You'll need to do this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#
use strict;             # Lets you know when you misspell variable names
use warnings;           # Warns of issues (using undefined variables
use autodie;            # Automatically kills the program if opens fail
use feature qw(say);

my @to_remove = qw(100 102 104 131 156);
opendir my $dir_fh, "dir_name";

my %files = map { $_.".txt" => 1 } @to_remove;
while ( my $file = < $dir_fh > ) {
    if ( exists $files{$file} ) {
        say qq(File "$file" is in the list);
    }
    else {
        say qq(File "$file" isn't in the list);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd transform each element of the array then use the smart-match operator:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Modern::Perl;

my @toremove = (100, 102, 104, 131, 156);
my @txt = map{$_.'.txt'}@toremove;
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    if ($_ ~~ @txt) {
        say "==> $_ : found";
    } else {
        say "$_ : NOT found";
    }
}

__DATA__
abc
def.txt
100
102.txt
131.abc
156.txt
```

**Output:**

```
abc : NOT found
def.txt : NOT found
100 : NOT found
==> 102.txt : found
131.abc : NOT found
==> 156.txt : found
```

Comment: The smartmatch operator has been marked as [experimental](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5180delta.html#The-smartmatch-family-of-features-are-now-experimental). They were changed again in 5.20, and I highly suggest not to use it since it's constantly evolving.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a couple of alternatives:

```
##  Shorthand hash definition
@toremove{100, 102, 104, 131, 156}= (1) x 5;

##  Using a glob instead of opendir
for (<D:/MYPATH/*>)
{
    ##  Use a regex for flexibility
    if (m:.*/(.+)$: and $toremove{$1})
    {
        print "Doing something to $_\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: **Wrong** you want `@toremove{100, 102, 104, 131, 156} = (1) x 5`

Comment: Thanks, Brad. I was not aware that the last four elements would be initialized empty.